# How to iterate over two dictionaries at once and get a result using values and keys from both

Tags: python, loops

```
def GetSale():#calculates expected sale value and returns info on the stock with              highest expected sale value
      global Prices
      global Exposure
      global cprice
      global bprice
      global risk
      global shares
      global current_highest_sale
      best_stock=' '
      for value in Prices.values():
          cprice=value[1]
          bprice=value[0]
          for keys, values in Exposure.items():
             risk=values[0]
             shares=values[1]
             Expected_sale_value=( (cprice - bprice ) - risk * cprice) * shares
             print (Expected_sale_value)
             if current_highest_sale < Expected_sale_value:
                current_highest_sale=Expected_sale_value
                best_stock=Exposure[keys]
     return best_stock +" has the highest expected sale value"
```

Above is my code currently. For some reason though, it appears to be doing the first loop, then the second, then the second, then the first, then the second. It appears to do the second loop each time it gets to it before going back to the first `for` loop. It is because of this that the answers I'm getting are not correct.

Comment: What *should* it do? The way you have the code structured, the second loop is inside the first, so it will do the second loop once for each iteration of the first loop.

Comment: Note that dictionaries are unordered. Looping over two dictionaries at once usually doesn't make sense unless they have the same keys.

Comment: I need it to do the second loop once for each iteration of the first loop because both of the dictionaries are the same length.I need information from both of them to calculate Expected_sale_value. But for some reason if I have more than one key/value pair in both dictionaries the math does strange things and doesnt always appear to come out right

Comment: They have the same keys. only the values are diffrent

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but answering the title, you can get both keys and values at the same time like this:

```
>>> d = {'a':5, 'b':6, 'c': 3}
>>> d2 = {'a':6, 'b':7, 'c': 3}
>>> for (k,v), (k2,v2) in zip(d.items(), d2.items()):
    print k, v
    print k2, v2


a 5
a 6
c 3
c 3
b 6
b 7
```

However, do mind that keys in dictionaries aren't ordered. Furthermore, if the two dictionaries do not contain the same number of keys, the code above will fail.

Comment: @aIKid Can we do this even if the two dictionaries do not have the same number of keys? I am having this very problem right now...

Comment: @CF84 The length of the iterable `zip()` returns should be equal to that of the shortest input, so if you have iterables of different sizes as input, for example `zip([1, 2, 3], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55])`, then it will still work, but the result will be `[(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]`. So the trailing values of the longer iterable(s) are ignored.

Comment: Also, be careful that dictionaries are not ordered, (but `OrderedDict`s are,) so when you iterate through dictionaries, the order of keys and values may not be what you'd expect. (In general it won't be in the same order as when you added them, for example.) So when you iterate through two dictionaries with the same keys simultaneously, the keys may not even appear in the same order.

Comment: @Ray is right on this.  Adding another key to d2, `d2 = {'c': 3, 'a':9, 'b':7, 'x':9}`, reorders the keys and gives different results.

Answer (score 19):

The question isn't well defined, and the answer accepted will fail for some dictionaries.  It relies on key ordering, which isn't guaranteed.  Adding additional keys to a dictionary, removing keys, or even the order they are added can affect the ordering.

A safer solution is to choose one dictionary, `d` in this case, to get the keys from, then use those to access the second dictionary:

```
d = {'a':5, 'b':6, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a':6, 'b':7, 'c': 3}
[(k, d2[k], v) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Result:

```
[('b', 7, 6), ('a', 6, 5), ('c', 3, 3)]
```

This isn't more complex than the other answers, and is explicit about which keys are being accessed.  If the dictionaries have different key orderings, say `d2 = {'x': 3, 'b':7, 'c': 3, 'a':9}`, consistent results are still given.

Comment: this idea only works if d2 has same keys as d, if d2 had a key 'foo' then it will be omitted since it didn't exist in dict d

Comment: it gives an error when d dict has a key which is not present in d2.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your problem, I would suggest you to create generator expression that navigates the two dictionary in pairs and using [max](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a custom key to calculate sale price to evaluate `expected_sale_price` and the corresponding stock

*Sample Data*

```
Prices = dict(zip(range(10), ((randint(1,100), randint(1,100)) for _ in range(10))))
Exposure = dict(zip(range(10), ((randint(1,100), randint(1,100)) for _ in range(10))))
```

*Sample Code*

```
def GetSale(Prices, Exposure):
    '''Get Sale does not need any globals if you pass the necessary variables as
       parameteres
    '''
    from itertools import izip
    def sale_price(args):
        '''
        Custom Key, used with the max function
        '''
        key, (bprice, cprice), (risk, shares) = args
        return ( (cprice - bprice ) - risk * cprice) * shares

    #Generator Function to traverse the dict in pairs
    #Each item is of the format (key, (bprice, cprice), (risk, shares))
    Price_Exposure = izip(Prices.keys(), Prices.values(), Exposure.values())


    #Expected sale price using `max` with custom key
    expected_sale_price = max(Price_Exposure, key = sale_price)
    key, (bprice, cprice), (risk, shares) =  expected_sale_price
    #The best stock is the key in the expected_sale_Price
    return "Stock {} with values bprice={}, cprice = {}, risk={} and shares={} has the highest expected sale value".format(key, bprice, cprice, risk, shares)
```

Answer (score -1):

just for loop on k in d... d and d2 have same keys so index on d[k] and d2[k] in the same for loop body

```
d  = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
d2 = {1:'x',2:'y',3:'z'}
for k in d:
    do_something(d[k],d2[k])
```