# Python: iterating over multiple dictionaries at once

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I know [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736709/how-to-iterate-over-two-dictionaries-at-once-and-get-a-result-using-values-and-k?answertab=active#tab-top) that it is possible to iterate over two different dictionaries at once:

```
d1 = {'a':5, 'b':6, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a':6, 'b':7, 'c': 4}
for (k1,v1), (k2,v2) in zip(d1.items(), d2.items()):
    print k1, v1
    print k2, v2
```

but how can this be efficiently extended to a list with, say, 20 different dictionaries which happen to have the same keys?

```
mylist=[d1, d2, d3, ..., d20]
```

Comment: [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mylist = [d1, d2, d3, ..., d20]
keys = mylist[0].keys()  # they must ALL have the same keys, mind....

for k in keys:
    for d in mylist:
        print k, d[k]
```

The direct translation would be something like:

```
for ... in zip(*map(dict.items, mylist)):
```

but what do you put in the ellipsis? You'd have to either name all those things, or have one big tuple-of-tuples that is difficult to operate on. I guess alternately you could do:

```
for big_tuple in zip(*map(dict.items, mylist)):
    for kv in big_tuple:
        k, v = kv
        print k, v
```

but that's longer and harder to handle than just storing the list of keys once and addressing each dictionary separately.