# Display the output of datatypes from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to display the output of datatypes from two dataframes.

`column_name, dbf datatype, df datatype` should be displayed.

Working code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from dbfread import DBF

csv_file = "bridges.csv"
dbf_file = "bridges.dbf"

def dbf_to_csv(path_to_dbf):
    '''Convert to .csv file,  display DBF and CSV column types'''
    csv_fn = path_to_dbf[:-4]+ ".csv"          
    print('\tCreating {}'.format(csv_fn)) 
    table = DBF(path_to_dbf)
    with open(csv_fn, 'w', newline = '') as f: 
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)     
        print('\t\tWriting converted data to {}'.format(csv_fn))
        for record in table:                   
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
        print('\n\n\t\tClosing converted data to {}\n\n'.format(csv_fn))


def main():
    path_to_dbf = "./bridges.dbf"
    
    print('\n\tPrinting the head of the .dbf file: {}'.format(dbf_file))
    dbf = DBF(dbf_file)
    dbf = pd.DataFrame(dbf)
    print(dbf.head(5))
    
    print('\n\tPrinting the head of the .csv file: {}'.format(csv_file))
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    print(df.head(5))
    
    ##  2.  read the column datatype and display    
    print('Printing column name and column datatype:')
    for name, dbf_type in dbf.dtypes.iteritems():
        print('\t{}\t\t{}'.format(name, dbf_type))

    
    print('Printing .csv column name and column datatype:')
    for name, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
        print('\t{}\t\t{}'.format(name, dtype))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After searching SO I found something along the lines of

```
    ##  2.  read the column datatype and display    
    print('Printing column name and column datatype:')
    dbf_type = dbf.dtypes.iteritems()
    df_type = df.dtypes.iteritems()
    for name, in zip(dbf.dtypes.iteritems(), df.dtypes.iteritems()):
        print('\t{}\t\t{}\t\t{}'.format(name, df_type, dbf_type))
```

This produces the error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Can anyone offer a solution or alternative method, please.

Comment: To print the column name(s) and dtype(s) of a DataFrame df you just use `print(df.columns.values, df.dtypes)`. No iteration is needed.

Comment: Definitely use `print(df.columns)` if you need to view the columns. To address the specific error, it's because `name` is a tuple. So when you're trying to str format in the print statement, it is attempting to fill a single `{}` with a tuple from name. From the docs,`df.iteritems` 'returns a tuple with the column name and the content as a Series'. This change should solve your problem `print('\t{}\t\t{}\t\t{}\t\t{}'.format(*name, df_type, dbf_type))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for on [How to iterate over two dictionaries at once....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736709/how-to-iterate-over-two-dictionaries-at-once-and-get-a-result-using-values-and-k).  A big thank you to [user2699](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754992/user2699)

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from dbfread import DBF

csv_file = "bridges.csv"
dbf_file = "bridges.dbf"
datatypes = "datatypes.csv"

def dbf_to_csv(path_to_dbf):
    '''Convert to .csv file,  display DBF and CSV column types'''
    csv_fn = path_to_dbf[:-4]+ ".csv"          
    print('\tCreating {}'.format(csv_fn)) 
    table = DBF(path_to_dbf)
    with open(csv_fn, 'w', newline = '') as f: 
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)     
        print('\t\tWriting converted data to {}'.format(csv_fn))
        for record in table:                   
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
        print('\n\n\t\tClosing converted data to {}\n\n'.format(csv_fn))


def main():
    ##  1.  read .dbf file formed by QField
    path_to_dbf = "./bridges.dbf"
    
    # print('\n\tPrinting the head of the .dbf file: {}'.format(dbf_file))
    dbf = DBF(dbf_file)
    dbf = pd.DataFrame(dbf)
    # print(dbf.head(5))
    
    # print('\n\tPrinting the head of the .csv file: {}'.format(csv_file))
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    # print(df.head(5))
    
    # ##  2.  read the column datatype and display    
    # print('Printing column name and column datatype:')
    # for name, dbf_type in dbf.dtypes.iteritems():
        # print('\t{}\t\t{}'.format(name, dbf_type))

    
    print('Printing .csv column name and column datatype:')
    # Create an empty Dictionary
    my_csv_dictionary = {}
    my_dbf_dictionary = {}
    for name, dtype in df.dtypes.items():
        # print('\t{}\t\t{}'.format(name, dtype))
        # ##  str(dtype) only returns value
        my_csv_dictionary.update({name:str(dtype)})
        
    for name, dtype in dbf.dtypes.items():
        # print('\t{}\t\t{}'.format(name, dtype))
        # ##  str(dtype) only returns value
        my_dbf_dictionary.update({name:str(dtype)})


    ##  write the datatypes to a .csv file
    ##  ensure UTF-B encoding for Postgres
    print('Printing Dict to screen')
    for k, v in my_csv_dictionary.items():
        print('{},\t{},\t {}'.format(k, v, my_dbf_dictionary[k]))
    
    
    print('Printing Dict to .csv')
    with open('gt.csv', 'w') as f:
        for k, v in my_csv_dictionary.items():
            f.write("%s, %s, %s\n" % (k, v, my_dbf_dictionary[k]))
    
    print('\n\n\t\tClosing converted data to {}\n\n')




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code displays to the screen (maybe not very neatly) in the format `key, dict1_value, dict2_value`

I have also added the code to write to a `.csv` file (in the same formatting as the screen display), this might save some time later.